# Dropdown list from EntityFramework is not displaying options

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Afternoon all, im new to mvc and entity framework.  But I have a question in reference to my model.

I have an entity framework model that looks like the following image:
[image]

I have combined these two tables into a model as named Marie_Testing.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;


namespace EDT_Test.Models.ViewModels
   {
   public partial class Marie_Testing
   {
    [Display(Name = "Client Ref:")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Created By:")]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public List<Title> allTitles { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Surname:")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Additional Surname:")]
    public string Surname2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Forename:")]
    public string Forename1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Additional Forename:")]
    public string Forename2 { get; set; }
```

I have a Create.cshtml page that uses the Marie_Testing model...

```
@model EDT_Test.Models.ViewModels.Marie_Testing

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @*@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.allClientData)*@

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Marie_Test</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedBy, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", style = "width:200px;background:E1EBF9;", @Value = "LazzM" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.allTitles, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select id="titleid" name="titlename" class="form-control">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.allTitles)
                    {
                        <option>@item.id</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have a HomeController.cs that is supposed to list the titles in the dropdown from the database upon the page being created.  This doesn't seem to work. Here is the code for the 'Create' Action Result.

```
 //required to get Client data from the Clients: Dbset 
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ////set the defaults (dropdown) of the page for the create of of a new record.
            Marie_Testing vmPopulateData = new Marie_Testing();

            List<Title> titles = (from t in db.Titles select t).ToList();
            vmPopulateData.allTitles = titles;

            return View(vmPopulateData);
        }

        //required to post ClientML table, vreate a parameter of client
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(ClientRecord client)
        {
            //validate the model and save to employee table.
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //this is the db set we are referencing             
                db.ClientRecords.Add(client);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(client);
        }
```

I can however run the current code and enter data successfully into the required database, however the Titles field isn't populated as i can see this when debugging and stepping through create code.

I'm not sure why the title dropdown is not being populated as i can see the model is referenced in the Create.cshtml and i can pick these properties from the model within the razor code.

I have seen some similar posts similar to my issue but i cannot find a way of solving the problem.

If anyone has any suggestions or pointers can you please let me know.

Comment: The `name` attribute of the `select` html element has to be the same as the ViewModel property `allTitles`. So basically: `<select name="allTitles">`

Comment: You dont seem to have a Title value in your view model? All I can see is the list of titles but no specific declaration to capture the actual title

Comment: And why is `ClientRecord client` the parameter of the `Create` ActionResult of type `ClientRecord` ? For it to work, the parameter has to be of the ViewModel type, so your function should look something like this:  `public ActionResult Create(Marie_Testing client)`

Comment: are you sure the data is present in title table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you add "value" attribute in option tag. 
I also assume that you should display item.Title1 as text, and not item.id (correct me if i am wrong)

please add

> value="@item.id"

to option tag otherwise it will not post selected value.

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.allTitles, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select id="titleid" name="titlename" class="form-control">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.allTitles)
                    {
                        <option value="@item.id">@item.Title1</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Also, if your select tag is empty and doesn't have any values, i would suggest to check if your table has some records.

Comment: They could also cast the Title list as a SelectListItem and then use                             @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TitleId, Model.allTitles, new {@class="form-control"}) for easier readability

Comment: @ KD - that works a treat.  Not 100% sure why this wasn't populating the first time round.   i do have another slight issue though.  The dropdown list is being populated with the titles but when i submit my form all fields are being submitted to the database apart from the Title filed.   Even though i can see these available in the dropdown, when i debug the page to see what the values are for each filed the Title field has a value of null?

Comment: You need to make sure the property name in "ClientRecord" class should match with what you have on form select Tag. It should be "titlename". Once you have correct property name and you add value="@item.id" in your options, it should post value and model should have it set.

Comment: @KD the property for Title generated by Entity Framework is generated is:  public string Title { get; set; }.  This does differ slightly in the model I want to use (Marie_Testing), the property in here is: public List<Title> allTitles { get; set; }.   I added this property in here as I want the title field in the web page to be a list ltem?

Comment: As you are not using HTML helpers for SELECT tag, you can change name your SELECT tag from "titlename" to => "Title". This will set required value on posting the form. Your view modal type and the type you are accepting in POST action are different, and while posting the form you just need to make sure you are having same property name with that.

Comment: @ KD, thank you for that, this does work as it should now.  you have been most helpful :)